# Does not work attr required if get it as JSON

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, html, required-field

I have the problem.

I send ajax request as **dateType: json**, and get **HTML** code, paste it as **$(selector).html(res.html)**, and browser don't understand attr **required="required"** and **type="email"**, does not works.

Only if I change **dateType** on HTML it works.

How can I make it work?

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  success: function (res) {
    $("#html").html(res.html);
  }
})
```

res:

```
{"status": true, "html": "<form id=\"ajax-form\"><input type=\"email\" name=\"email\" required=\"required\" /></form>"}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6a2Ja/2/

Comment: and we should guess the code?!

Comment: The JSON is invalid. Strings **must** be denoted by double quotes, not single quotes.

Comment: i add jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/6a2Ja/2/

Comment: Your submit button needs to be *inside* your `<form>`, not outside.  That's the issue here.  The HTML works fine.  Updated deno: http://jsfiddle.net/6a2Ja/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML works fine.  The `<input>` has all the attributes on it that it should.  The problem is that your submit button is in the wrong spot.  It needs to be *inside* the form.

Do that, then it works fine.  So, basically make your JSON:

```
{"status": true, "html": "<form id=\"ajax-form\"><input type=\"email\" name=\"email\" required=\"required\" /><input type=\"submit\" value=\"send\" /></form>"}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/6a2Ja/3/

Comment: Yeah nice, thanks you. but that if i do not have buttons "submit" in form?
example: [http://jsfiddle.net/6a2Ja/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/6a2Ja/4/)

Comment: @Swain: If the submit button isn't in the form, then it won't know to act on that form.  You'd then need to use JavaScript to have the button submit the form.

Comment: Thank u very much for answer. rewrite my code, now works fine.